# What's the meaning of "exposure " in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

From [a reading test on IELTS PTE Online](http://practicepteonline.com/ielts-reading-test-42/) titled "Allergy Testing,

> A person does not become allergic to a particular substance until after the first **exposure**. However, in some cases, even trace amounts of a substance, such as peanuts or seafood in a mother's breast milk, can cause an allergic reaction in a subsequent **exposure**.

Does this "exposure" mean

> [uncountable] exposure (to something) the state of being in a place or situation where there is no protection from something harmful or unpleasant
>
> Source: [Oxford Learner's Dictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/exposure)

If it is, why before the second "exposure" has "a"? Because according to the Longman Dictionary, it is an uncountable noun.

Comment: *Exposure* is used here in the sense of an event of exposure. The first reference talks of "first exposure," which itself suggests there could be more "exposures," i.e., incidents of exposure. HTH. It's a general phenomenon and is nothing specific to "exposure" *per se*.

Comment: The Q is based on an incorrect interpretation of the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Answer:  The correct term is count noun and noncount noun. 
Some nouns can be both.
Exposure is one of those nouns.

The usage is correct in the paragraph in both sentence one and two.

Source: Check out MacMillan Dictionary at https://www.macmillandictionary.com - you may need a better dictionary.

Definition for "exposure" showing when this noun either a count noun, a noncount noun, or both is at this link:

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/exposure

Excellent source. College University recommended.

Confusion over when to use determiners "a" or "an"

Use a, an, and the where they are required.
 [With  singular count nouns:

- Simple rule:  Use "a" before words beginning with consonant sounds, including those spelled with an initial pronounced "h" and those spelled with vowels that are sounded like consonants (a historian; a one o'clock appointment) ["one" sounds like "w," etc.]  Use "an" before words that begin with vowel sounds, including those spelled with an initial silent h [an organism, an L (sounds like "El" or the e vowel when pronounced. (Little Brown Handbook, 11th Ed. P. 865, Pearson Education, 2010. Book. /LBH/)

Sentence two:  subsequent + exposure makes this a compound subject.  Using "a" to introduce "[s]ubsequent exposure" is correct. (LBH Pg. 231)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could be simpler than that. See my comment at OP.

Comment: Your comment doesn't answer the poster's question(s).  He states his dictionary lists "exposure" as a noncount noun. It's best to answer all his questions or reject it as not applicable here.

Comment: My comment deals with all, countable or not. It explains that "exposure" is nothing special in the first place. Try and get the drift. Good Luck.

Comment: It's best not to further confound one's confusion.

Comment: He doesn't seem to be confused. He seems to have a poor dictionary. Is he a Engl as 2nd Lang student?  He's smart enough to try & apply grammar rules to a noun. Don't count him out.

Comment: Andrew T: At some point, a good English only reference dictionary needs to be a source you also check or have handy. Longman introduces Korean, Japanese, Chinese, Indonesian speakers to basic English study material--at a cost. I'm a Native English speaker. I live in Japan. If conflict btwn Longman &Merriam -Webster, go with MW over Longman.  Keep trying. You're doing great.

Comment: I agree about needing a better dictionary. The (original) OED.COM lists 'exposure' as a count noun, and gives as examples "1796   *E. Burke Let. to Noble Lord in Wks. (1815) VIII. 44*   'Whatever in his pedigree has been dulcified by **an exposure** to the influence of heaven.'" and "1802   *W. Paley Nat. Theol. xvi. 304*   'So unusual **an exposure** of the globe of the eye.'" http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/66730?redirectedFrom=exposure#eid

Comment: @SteveB053 I'm not sure why you replied to me on this answer, but I'm not the asker... user337359 is the asker :)